# Is this proof of the radius of convergence correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**Claim**: Suppose that the coefficients of the power series $\sum a_nz^n$ are integers, infinitely many of which are distinct from $0$. Prove that the radius of convergence is at most 1. (question from Rudin)

**My Proof**: Let $R$ denote the radius of convergence and $\alpha=\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. Assume, for contradiction, that $R>1$. Then, we have $\frac{1}{\alpha}>1 \implies \limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} < 1\implies \limsup|a_n|<1$. Since $a_n$ is an integer, $\limsup a_n=0$. Thus, there exists $N$ such that $n \geq N \implies a_n=0$. However, this contradicts the fact that there are infinitely many distinct integers in the range of $(a_n)$. $\square$

This is different from other proofs I could find so I'm wondering if this is also correct. Thanks!

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: You could get rid of one level of indirectness, though: We positively have $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\ge 1$, hence $R\le 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

My proof: there is a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ such that $|(a_{n_k})| \ge 1$ for all $k$.

This shows that $(a_n)$ does not converge to $0$. Hence $ \sum a_n$ is divergent.

Thus,the power series $\sum a_nz^n$ is divergent at $z=1.$ Consequence: $R \le 1.$